# PHP SimpleXML, insert in database

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

I am trying to read urls from my database and parse them using SimpleXML. Currently i have the following code:

```
$sites = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sources");

foreach($sites as $site) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($site['source_url']);
        $stories = $this->_filter_out_headlines($site['source_name'], $html);
        $this->_add_stories_to_db($stories, $site['source_id']);
    }
```

But i get the following error message: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_query  $sites is a statement **HANDLE**. it is not the data you're expecting to get back from the query.

Comment: @MarcB Wow how rude.

Comment: @doug: how so? "Read the Friendly Manual" is rude? Get your mind out of the gutter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following change in your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sources");

while($site = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($site['source_url']);
    $stories = $this->_filter_out_headlines($site['source_name'], $html);
    $this->_add_stories_to_db($stories, $site['source_id']);
}
```